# C UDP server on background using thread

Tags: c, server, udp

Using thread, I wanted to launch UDP server on background.
But the server start and loop forever checking if any packet is received.
The same thread work fine if I use TCP server instead.

the test code is the following:

```
int udp_server_listen () {
    printf("udp_server_listen \n");
    int res;    
    unsigned char rsp_buf[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in src;
    socklen_t srclen;
    memset(&src, 0, sizeof(src));
    srclen = sizeof(src);

    listen(s , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    int c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    int client_sock;
    while( (client_sock = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&src, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("OK \n");
    }
}

void *thread_udp_cr_listen (void *v)
{
    udp_server_listen();
    return NULL;
}

int  s;
int main()
{
    printf("start test \n");

    struct sockaddr_in *local = malloc(sizeof (struct sockaddr_in *));      
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); // UDP
    printf("create socket end\n");
    int reusaddr = 1;
    int reusport = 1;
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reusaddr, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        printf("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed \n");
    }
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &reusport, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        printf("setsockopt(SO_REUSEPORT) failed \n");
    }
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 2;  /* 30 Secs Timeout */
    tv.tv_usec = 0;  // Not init'ing this can cause strange errors
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));
    fcntl(s, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    printf(" Bind to a specific network interface and a specific local port\n");
    int i = 0;
    for(;i<6;i++)
    {
            if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local)) < 0)
            {
                printf("bind Faild %d\n", i);
                sleep(1);
                continue;
            }
        break;
    }       
    error = pthread_create(&udp_cr_server_thread, NULL, &thread_udp_cr_listen, NULL);
    if (error<0)
    {
        printf("thread error \n");
    }
    pthread_join(udp_cr_server_thread, NULL);   
}
```

Comment: You do know that UDP is an *unconnected* protocol? You don't accept connection like you do in TCP, instead you just receive datagrams.

Comment: You could solve many issues is you don't use a pointer for the `local` socket address.

Comment: Can you explain what it is you want to do exactly? You specifically wrote code that loops forever waiting for datagrams. If that's not what you want .. what do you want?

Comment: By the way, I really don't see a need for threads in your program. You start a thread and then immediately wait for it to exit. If your main thread doesn't do anything else but wait for the network thread to exit, why use threads in the first place?

Comment: Also, if `bind` fails there's often no use in retrying.

Comment: Lastly, does your program really *build*? You define the global variable `s` *after* you use it in the `udp_server_listen` function.

Comment: I didn't past the whole code. I have a main program that contain other thread.

Answer (score 2):

You have one serious problem here:

```
struct sockaddr_in *local = malloc(sizeof (struct sockaddr_in *));
```

because you're just allocating the size of a pointer instead of the size of the struct itself.

This should of course be:

```
struct sockaddr_in *local = malloc(sizeof (struct sockaddr_in));
```

---

Two more problems with the same variable in this line:

```
        if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local)) < 0)
```

This should be:

```
        if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)local, sizeof(*local)) < 0)
```